# Cannot install googleapiclient on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, raspberry-pi3, google-api-client

I have recently installed PyCharm on my Raspberry Pi 3 b+ (Running version 9 [Stretch]) and I am having some trouble installing the googleapiclient package on PyCharm and the system.

When I perform a pip/pip3 install for this package I receive an error stating:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement googleapiclient (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for googleapiclient

This is the same error message that I receive on PyCharm when it tries to do a pip install.
Python 3.7.3 has been installed and 2.7.13 from default.
PyCharm project interpreter is running 3.5.
I have performed an apt-get update & upgrade also.

I have been able to successfully install other packages with pip/pip3 as well.

Am I missing any other packages/dependencies?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you're just using the wrong name. Try `pip install google-api-python-client` as specified [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)

Comment: Thanks, was following the import statement off some old code I had and assumed that was the same package name too.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue even though I installed the packages in my cmd Pycharm was not recognizing it, so executing the same command in Pycharm terminal solved the issue for me.