# Cannot install googleapiclient on PyCharm clinet

Tags: python, api, pycharm

Hey I'am trying to work with youtube API and for that I need to import a module,
the command for importing is: `from googleapiclient.discovery import build`
I need to install that so what i am doing is [pressing this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QuOQ.png)

after pressing that it's telling me that there is an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgOqX.png)

I have tried to go to the cmd and type `pip install googleapiclient` by myself but when I do that this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx78I.png) appears
I really don't  know what to do I saw this one [Cannot install googleapiclient on PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804061/cannot-install-googleapiclient-on-pycharm) but I didn't understand the answer with the pycharm terminal
can someone tell me what do I need to do in order to install **googleapiclient**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named googleapiclient.discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571392/no-module-named-googleapiclient-discovery) if using python3 try `pip3 --install google-api-python-client` else `pip` I googled your topic title and found another on stackoverflow. Please look before you make a question.

Comment: I saw this one but when I type that in the cmd this is what happens https://imgur.com/KlsFDva

Comment: My bad remove `--install` and make it `install`

Comment: ok did it what happens is this long message appears https://imgur.com/ea4Mbkv and then i tried again to run the program and this is what happens  https://imgur.com/Olw59ma